# Refer to list element name via a variable

Tags: r

I would like to ask if there is a way to refer to a list element name via a variable:

```
Labels <- vector(mode = "list") # Make a list called "Labels"
Labels[[1]] <- c(1,3,5,7) # Assign value to the first list element
names(Labels)[1] <- "Name" # Assign the name "Name" to the first list element
print(Labels)
print(Labels$Name)
# [1] 1 3 5 7

# Now I have the name of the first list element "Name"
# in the variable "ElementName"
ElementName <- "Name"

# How R will understand in the next line
# that I refer to the value "Name" of the variable "ElementName"
# in order to get 
# [1] 1 3 5 7

print(Labels$ElementName)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `[[` to extract the `list` elements.

```
Labels[[ElementName]]
#[1] 1 3 5 7
```

If we are using the name of the `list` element, we use quotes

```
Labels[['Name']]
#[1] 1 3 5 7
```

For more info, check `?"[["` or `?Extract`

Comment: Thank you a lot akrun. I didn't know that.